# Splitting a string 8 characters at the time

Tags: c

I am trying to divide a buffer as I go along, 8 characters at the time.

I have my buffer running correctly, the only thing I do not have a clue is to how to do this.

What I have for now is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void splittingFunction(FILE *filePtr, long fileLength)
{
    char *buffer=(char*)malloc(fileLength+1);
    if(!buffer)
        printf("Out of Memory");
    n=fread(buffer, fileLength, 1, filePtr);

    for(i=0; i<fileLength; i++)
        printf("%c",buffer[i]);

    free(buffer);
}
```

So this will print me to the screen something like this:

```
10111010001101000001000000111010001101000011001010010000001100001011100100110110101111001001000000110111101100110001000000111010001101000011001010010000001100100011001010110000101100100001011100000110100001010010101000110100001100101001000000100111001101001011001110110100001110100001000000100101101101001011011100110011
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
arr[]={"10111010","00011010","00000100", ...}
```

I know this might sound silly, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You may also consider preprocessing the file with tools like *sed* and *awk*.

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate the length of your array `arrSize` (it'll be the buffer length divided by 8, plus 1 if the remainder isn't zero)
2. Create a variable-length array of `char[9]` with the size computed in step 1, i.e. `char arr[arrSize][9]`
3. Use a `for` loop from 0 to `arrSize` (non-inclusive). Calculate the position in the buffer using `i * 8`, and copy either 8 bytes (if it's not the last string) or less (if it is the last string). You can use either `strncpy` or, if your platform has it, `strlcpy`, which is slightly safer, to do this. Make sure to put the null terminator at the end if you're not using `strlcpy`. Also, make sure not to overflow the buffer by writing more than 9 characters into it (shouldn't happen with `strncpy` or `strlcpy`, but if you do something else, watch out for this).

Comment: "3. Use a for loop for 0 to `arrsize`" - perhaps you meant `arrsize-1`?

Comment: @BobJarvis Non-inclusive; `i < arrSize`. Generally "to" is `<` and "through" is `<=` You're right, though, that I could have made that clearer. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks you. Should I use a for inside a for?

Comment: @Sombrito Shouldn't need to (I'd just use `strncpy` or `strlcpy`), although you could. Be careful when you do the last string, though. If it's less than eight characters, only copy the number of characters that are left (plus the null terminator, of course). Otherwise you'll run past the end of the buffer. `strncpy` or `strlcpy` should handle that for you, if you use them.

Comment: And if you declare `arr` on the stack in a subroutine, make sure you don't return it to the caller or you may find yourself living in a shotgun shack and you may find yourself living in another part of the world and and you may find yourself behind the wheel of a large automobile and you may find yourself in a beautiful house with a beautiful wife and you may ask yourself "Well, how did I get here?"

Comment: you'll also need to ensure the string is NUL terminated as `strncpy` will only do that on the last chunk

Comment: @BobJarvis Lol, true. If you want to return it out of the function, you can't use an array. Use `malloc`'ed memory instead in that case (and remember to `free` it when you're done with it).

Comment: @ChrisTurner Yep, as I said, make sure the null terminator gets put at the end if you're not using `strlcpy`. This is why I generally prefer `strlcpy` on platforms that have it.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Thank yo for your help, however could you show me how you would code it? Thanks

Comment: Im struggling particularly in  "Calculate the position in the buffer using i * 8", not sure where I should use it

Comment: @Sombrito You'll learn more if you write it yourself, but the gist: If you have `i` be 0, 1, 2, etc., then `i * 8` will be 0, 8, 16, etc. These will be the addresses for the string slices that you can then copy into your array.

Comment: I still can't get it to function. I have done this, not sure if remotely correct

 _italic_ **bold  '  char arr[arrSize][9];


    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i*=8)
    {
        strncpy(arr, buffer, 8);
    }

    free(buffer);
} '**

Comment: @Sombrito My comments: 1) Add one to `i` on each run through the loop, don't multiply. 2) Use `&buffer[i * 8]` as the source pointer for `strncpy`. 3) Each time through the loop, make sure to set the null terminator at the end of the string after you call `strncpy`!

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I have done as you said, apart from the null pointer (which I don't know how to set). Its giving me a Seg Fault, which could be from that

Comment: @Sombrito Post what you've got, and I'll critique it.

Comment: inline `for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        strncpy(arr, &buffer[i*8], 8);

    }

    free(buffer);
}`

I got this, just as you said, the only thing I can't seem to do is to set the null terminator

Comment: @Sombrito 1) Notice what you've set as the destination pointer for `strncpy`. Do you want to write your chars directly to the array, or into the strings inside the array? 2) If there are 8 characters in a C string, what should come immediately after those 8 characters?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I would like to write it to the strings inside the array

Comment: @CharlesSrstka So far I have this inline `    printf("\n%d", arrSize);
    char arr[arrSize][9];


    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
       strncpy(arr[i], &buffer[i*8], 8);
       arr[i][9]='\0';

    }

    free(buffer);
}
`

Comment: One little mistake here; which byte of the string should get the null terminator? (Hint: what index do C arrays start at?)

Comment: Well, the byte of the string to get the null terminator should be the last, by that I mean `arr[i][9]='\0`. C-arrays start at index 0.
I'm clueless now

Comment: @Sombrito Spell it all out. Starting at zero, what are the eight indexes where your characters will go? And then where does the terminator need to be?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka According to that, the charactes would be stored from 'arr[i][0]' to 'arr[i][7]' where the null terminator would be 'arr[i][8]'. Again not sure if im thinking this correctly. I have this ' for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
       strncpy(arr, &buffer[i*8], 8);
       arr[i][8]='\0';

    }'

Comment: Just to say that when I run the debugger, it gives me a Seg Fault on ` char arr[arrSize][9];`

Comment: @Sombrito Yup, in an array of size 9, the last element has index 8, because the indices start at 0. If you write to element 9, you overflow the buffer and can either cause a crash, or worse. Same goes for `arr[arrSize]`—that's an overflow. The last element is at `arrSize - 1`.

Comment: I got it working by doing this `char **arr=(char**)malloc(arrSize*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(char *)malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    }



    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
       strncpy(arr[i], &buffer[i*8], 8);
       arr[i][8]='\0';

    }
    for(i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        puts(arr[i]);
    }

    free(buffer);
}`

So thanks a lot man, sorry for any nuisance. Give yourself a beer. You deserve it :D

Comment: @Sombrito That's the way to go if you have too much data to allocate on the stack. Just make sure to `free` all those pointers when you're done with them (loop through first and free all the strings, then free `arr`).

Answer (score 1):

Print up to 8 characters at a time using `"%.*s"`.

`"%s"` with a precision field prints up to that many characters.

```
size_t n = fread(buffer, fileLength, 1, filePtr);
int delta; 
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i += delta) {
  delta = 8;
  if (fileLength - i < delta) delta = fileLength - i;
  printf("\"%.*s\"," delta, buffer + i);
}
```

Or simplify by appending a *null character* to `buffer[]`

```
size_t n = fread(buffer, fileLength, 1, filePtr);
buffer[n] = '\0';

for(size_t i=0; i<n; i += 8) {
  printf("\"%.8s\",", buffer + i);
}
```